# Connect mysql via ssh

Tags: c++, mysql, ssh-tunnel

how can I create a connection via ssh in c ++ in mysql?

It should work like this:

```
mysql -L -u <local database username> -h <database server ip address> -p
```

In any case, I would like to create the connection to the mysql database from a computer that is not in the same network and thus exchange data.

I just don't understand how I get the values ​​from `mysql_real_connect();` should start.

Is there any other way that would work?

Comment: Either spawn a copy of `ssh` in the background with the `-L` flag to forward a port or use libssh2 to do the same. Which would you prefer?

Comment: libssh2 has a trivial tcp/ip forwarding example here: https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/example/tcpip-forward.c

Comment: @Botje I try the libssh2 connection

Comment: it's a little too difficult for me. I don't understand the code

Comment: @Botje How do copy the ssh? where should i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trivial implementation using boost::process:

```
bp::child c(bp::search_path("ssh"), "-N", "-L", "23306:localhost:3306", "user@hostname);
```

You can connect to localhost:23306 while `c` is alive.

Comment: `c` is the connection, right? should I also set something on the server? e.g. the bind ip address

Comment: c is a SSH connection that keeps open a port forward. The server should be listening to localhost:3306 (via tcp).

Comment: is it possible to use the SSH connection in mysql?

Comment: You automatically use it by connecting through the SSH tunnel: port 23306 on localhost is connected to port 3306 on the SSH server host.

Comment: Can I use commands like `mysql_init()` or `mysql_stmt_bind_param()`?

Comment: You still need to call `mysql_real_connect`; the line above just ensures you _can_ connect to localhost port 23306.

Comment: Is it normal that when I type in to a terminal `ssh -N -L 23306:localhost:3306 username@ip-address` (in my case) `-p 16000` in  that I wait and I get no access to the server? There display no error message

Comment: Yes. The -N option skips the shell session you normally get from ssh. This command is purely to establish the port forward. Connect to mysql in another terminal. Also read the ssh manpage for other options such as -f

Comment: Ah, yes when I try to type this command without `-N` in, it works that I get access to whrite :) I made a little bit of research about how to whrite a commad with my password in one line (so I dont must type in the password of ssh manualy) and I saw that I can use `sshpass`, is there another solution for this, maby with a second line in the code with the `boost::process` function?

Comment: Switch to SSH keys. passwords are a pain in the ass to automate.

Comment: ok I can try to remove the password. But what about the connection command from mysql? should I `mysql_real_connect (conn, "localhost", "User", "password", "DB", 3306, NULL, 0);`
 enter? It doesnt work

Comment: Repeating myself for the fourth time now: you need to connect to localhost on the port your forwarded (the first number after -L, 23306 in my example), not 3306.

Comment: Oh yeah it shoud work now :) Thanks for the help and for your patience